# Spring creates proxy using CGlib despite class implements multiple interfaces

Tags: spring, proxy, spring-aop, cglib

In my application, I have a class X that implements interface A and interface B. I’ve implemented an aspect using spring AOP and AspectJ with a pointcut on every method from the interface A.

While debugging the app, I noticed that Spring creates a proxy using CGLIB instead of JDK Dynamic Proxy.  What’s the reason of such behaviour? Shouldn’t be the proxy created as Dynamic Proxy instead, as the class X implements an interfaces? I don’t understand it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you use Spring Boot, not plain Spring. In contrast to Spring proper, Boot defaults to CGLIB even for interface proxies, which needs to be overridden. More specifically, you need to put this into your `application.properties`:

```
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false
```

See also my answers here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61390594/1082681
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74500968/1082681

Comment: I’m using pure Spring, configured via XML, a legacy project. When I set proxy-target-class to false, I’m getting redundant means it’s false by default..The pointcut is defined for every AuthorisationTokenServices interface method implemented by DefaultServiceToken (OAuth library). The purpose of use of the aspect is to handle DuplicateKeyException and repeat token request. The method is annotated as @Transactional.. May it be the reason?

Comment: It is hard to reason about invisible code. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. P.S.: Can you debug invisible code? I cannot. I already regret that I wasted my time, writing an answer based on an educated guess caused by a question with way too little information.